# Change direction of Corona/LUA object

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

HI my object is moving right to left how can i change this to from up to down ?

```
function movebadc1(self,event)
        if self.x < -50 then
        self.x =300
        self.y = 300
        self.speed = math.random (2,6)
        self.initY = self.y
        self.amp = math.random (20,100)
        self.angle = math.random (1,360)

        else 
                self.x = self.x - self.speed
                self.angle = self.angle + .1
                self.y = self.amp * math.sin(self.angle)+self.initY
        end
end
```

Regards Kevin

Comment: First of all, you're using degrees instead of radians. Try:

    self.angle = math.random() * math.pi * 2

to get the angle in radians. Radians describe an angle just like degrees do, but instead of going from 0 to 360, they go from 0 to 2π (~6.28). The only difference is that you can use radians in your trigonometry methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change from right to left, to up to down, supposing you also want other behavior to remain the same, change the three following lines:

```
            self.x = self.x - self.speed
            self.angle = self.angle + .1
            self.y = self.amp * math.sin(self.angle)+self.initY
```

to

```
            self.y = self.y + self.speed
            self.angle = self.angle + .1
            self.x = self.amp * math.sin(self.angle)+self.initX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cos() instead of sin(). It will work hopefully.